# trying to start server on rails " rails s" and i keep getting error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
image not found - /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.3.7/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.3.7/lib/mysql2.rb:9
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `require'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler.rb:122:in `require'
from /Users/apple/Sites/simple_cms/config/application.rb:7
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:52:in `require'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:52
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:49:in `tap'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:49
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to run `bundle install` command in project dir